# Reputation being shown in my Stack Exchange chat profile is too high

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat, profile-page

The reputation shown in my [Stack Exchange chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/6040/matt) is almost 8000 points too much
[image: picture of my cross site rep being too high]

If I add up the reputation from my various SE accounts (including those below 200) I get 12335

Something is amiss!

Comment: Total reps in your [flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204723/matt-ellen/flair) looks about right, so that's certainly a bug in the SE total rep count.

Comment: If you feel you have too much rep you can spend it as a bounty on one of my answers :-)

Comment: Looks like it's not a localised eror. I looked mine up and I see a discrepancy of ~1.3k. [15277](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27969/shawn-chin) vs [13960](http://stackexchange.com/users/40044?tab=accounts).

Comment: One of two things is amiss here: 1) the fact that you are willingly giving up 8K of (freeish) rep, 2) my morality in saying you should keep the rep.  You decide.

Comment: @casperOne: Oh, sure! I could have paraded around town in my beautiful 20k coat, or at least that's what it would have looked like. If anyone had checked the label, they'd see it was just a cheap knock off. What a fool I'd look when the error was inevitably corrected!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We deployed some changes to chat this morning, to switch over to [API v2](https://stackapps.com/questions/2688/register-for-the-stack-exchange-v2-0-api-private-beta) (we like dogfooding). It looks like I missed the linked-meta check when doing this; it has been re-added, and I have refreshed your account (this normally happens once an hour); you are now back at 12.4k as desired.

Comment: Is there also a hidden meta which mirrors the SO reputation? Otherwise I don't get how [I come to 46.4k](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/7221/paulo-ebermann).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - it's showing 36.1k now.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I refreshed **Matt's** details; not the entire system. I'm sure it'll fix itself within an hour

Comment: @Marc: My point was that 46k still looked too high, even considering your explanation. But it might be that I have a bad overview about my total reputation across the network - the refresh to 36k shows that my SO rep rep was not doubled, and I really have 11k rep outside of SO+MSO (which was doubled before). Looks like my mass of 101-rep accounts still sum up. Sorry for troubling.

Comment: @MarcGravell - on that score I notice that [my profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/40/chrisf) is only showing the badges from DIY (my parent site). It that by design?

Comment: @ChrisF do you know, I don't think we've **ever** shown more than that; I doubt we even noticed... probably not by conscious design, no. Lemme see what would be involved in fixing that...

Comment: @ChrisF well, it wouldn't be *immediately* available, I don't think...

Comment: @MarcGravell - no worries. I'd not noticed before either. It was only this question that made me look.

Answer (score 11):

It seems like meta accounts are being included, even though they just mirror your reputation from the parent sites.

If you sum the reputation of all of your accounts, including your meta accounts (but apparently excluding discuss.area51?) it sums to 20112 reputation <sup>[[try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%0Aaccounts%20%3D%0A%09english%3A%20%7Brep%3A%204894%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09stackoverflow%3A%20%7Brep%3A%203807%7D%0A%09programmers%3A%20%7Brep%3A%202030%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09metastackoverflow%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20307%7D%0A%09area51%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20166%7D%0A%09superiser%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20153%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09philosophy%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20146%7D%0A%09bitcoin%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20143%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09bicycles%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20118%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09wordpress%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%7D%0A%09serverfault%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%7D%0A%09cstheory%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09math%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09linguistics%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%09japanese%3A%20%7Brep%3A%20101%2C%20hasMeta%3A%20yes%7D%0A%0Aalert%20(%0A%20%20for%20name%2C%20site%20of%20accounts%0A%20%20%20%20if%20site.hasMeta%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20site.rep%20*%202%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20site.rep%0A).reduce%20(a%2C%20b)%20-%3E%20a%20%2B%20b%0A)]</sup>. This is close enough to your chat profile's value that I think I'm right and the difference is probably due to caching.

Comment: This sounds about right. Did the sums for my account, and the difference is surprisingly close to my Meta reps (not exact, but close).

Comment: I agree, this looks like the cause.